# Запретить вставку определенных символов в input | JS / Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть input:

```
<input id="Phone" class="i" placeholder="" value="" maxlength="17" onkeypress="validate(event)">
```

И должно быть так, чтобы туда можно было писать только цифры (0-9), пробел, - и +. Реализую это через js, вот так:

```
function validate(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
  var regex = /[0-9\s\+\-]|\./;
  if( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

И все вроде бы хорошо, писать ничего кроме заданного в regex нельзя, но прикол в том, что запрещенное можно вставлять! Через ctrl+v. Как это обойти? (именно путем js/jquery, type="number" не подходит).

Comment: При этом, конечно же, желательно не убирать саму возможность что-либо вставлять в инпут, ибо это было бы глупо.

Comment: Еще скорее всего можно не только вставлять, также сделать drag&drop текста в инпут. А на телефоне еще T9 вам будет все портить)) Выход: не делать запрет на ввод, а вместо этого показывать ошибку, что введено не номер телефона

Comment: То есть нет никакого адекватного способа сделать именно запрет ввода? :(

Comment: Если и есть -  я его не знаю. Но мне кажется, что нету.

Comment: Не подойдёт type="tel"? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel

Answer (score 1):

Есть в js замечательное событие - onpaste. Оно и призвано предотвращать вставку нежелательного текста:

```js
function validate(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
  var regex = /[0-9\s\+\-]|\./;
  if( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}

document.getElementById('Phone').onkeypress = function() {
  validate(event);
}

document.getElementById('Phone').onpaste = function() {
  validate(event);
}
```

```html
<input id="Phone" class="i" placeholder="" value="" maxlength="17">
```

Comment: Привет! Спасибо большое за ответ. Оно также предотвратит т9 и drag&drop?

Comment: @Денис, ну, в таком виде любой paste предотвратит - просто потому что по этому событию у меня вызывается та же самая Ваша функция, что и по keypress. Это не совсем правильно - если Вы хотите, чтобы номера телефонов всё-таки можно было вставлять копипастом, то нужно тогда написать какую-то другую функцию проверки по событию onpaste (сейчас в принципе ничего нельзя вставить копипастом)

Answer (score 0):

Можно навесить (сразу три для подстраховки?)

```
<input id="Phone" class="i" placeholder="" value="" maxlength="17" oninput="validate(this)" onchange="validate(this)" onpaste="validate(this)">
```

и функцией validate брать value поля, вырезать запрещенные символы (replace) и вставлять в поле новый value

Answer (score 0):

Эта функция разрешает вставку только чисел и выражений с экспонентой.

```
function handlePaste(e) {
  const regex = /[0-9\s\+\-]|\./;
  let clipboardData, pastedData;

  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
  pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');

  !regex.test(pastedData) ? this.value = '' : this.value = Number(pastedData)
}

document.querySelector('#Phone').addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);
```